# ERROR: 'Checker 'xor_module_b' not found. Instantiation 'x0_1' must be of a visible checker.'?

Tags: verilog, digital-logic, vlsi, register-transfer-level

What is this error 'Checker 'xor_module_b' not found.  Instantiation 'x0_1' must be of a visible checker.'? I am writing verilog code in behavioral model by using module instantiation. While compiling i am getting the error. Portion of code and error is attached.

```
module CSSA4_4bit_modified_b(s,cin,g,G,GP,a,b);
input cin,g,G,GP;
input [7:0] a,b;
output wire [7:0] s;
wire [6:0] c0;
wire [3:0] c1;
wire [2:0] pro;
wire [7:0] s0;
wire [3:0] s1;

always@(a,b,cin,g,G,GP)
begin
//Subblock 1
//Sum bit 0
xor_module_b x0_1(.a(a[0]), .b(b[0]),.s0(s0[0]));
xor_module_b x0_2(.a(s0[0]),.b(cin), .s0(s[0]));
and_logic_b  a0 (.a(s0[0]), .b(cin), .out(pro[0]));
//end

//Sum bit 1
FA_b         FA_b1(.a(a[1]), .b(b[1]),  .c(g),.sum(s0[1]),.cout(c0[0]));
xor_module_b x1 (.a(s0[1]),.b(pro[0]),.s0(s[1]));
and_logic_b  a1 (.a(s0[1]),.b(pro[0]),   .out(pro[1]));
//end

//Sum bit 2
FA_b         FA_b2(.a(a[2]), .b(b[2]),  .c(c0[0]),.sum(s0[2]),.cout(c0[1]));
xor_module_b x2 (.a(s0[2]),.b(pro[1]),.s0(s[2]));
and_logic_b  a2 (.a(s0[2]),.b(pro[1]),.out(pro[2]));
//end.......continued
//Sum bit 7
FA_b FA_b1_7_1(.a(a[7]),.b(b[7]),.c(c0[5]), .sum(s0[7]),.cout(c0[6]));
FA_b FA_b1_7_2(.a(a[7]),.b(b[7]),.c(c1[2]), .sum(s1[3]),.cout(c1[3]));
sum_select_mux_b M1_7(.Sum(s[7]),.Sum0(s0[7]),.Sum1(s1[3]),.C8k(cin));
//End of subblock 2
//End of CSSA 4-4 bit
end
endmodule
```

[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThHnC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not instance a module inside an always.

Remove the *always@(a,b,cin,g,G,GP)*

---

You don't need the always here but in case you DO need it:
Listing your variable in the always is dangerous. If you forget one you are likely to get mismatches between simulation and reality (gates). Better to let the compiler work it out by using: always @( * )

You can use it in test benches but I can't remember ever needing it.

Comment: yes, removed. Errors are also eliminated. All the modules instantiated are written in behavioral modelling inside always block. Now i have to instantiate this top module CSSA4_4bit_modified_b in some other code. How to do that?

Comment: The same way you did with the *xor_module_b*, the *and_logic_b*, the *FA_b* modules etc.

Comment: so i have removed the always block. All the modules instantiated are written in behavioral modelling inside always block. Is the code of top module in behavioral model even now? after instantiating it in another module, will that be in behavioural model?

Comment: can i write a testbench for this top module 'CSSA4_4bit_modified_b'? If yes, then how to proceed? This is my final year project. Have to do verification in cadence tool in next step. for that i have to write testbench. Am i right?

Comment: Everything is behavioral until you synthesis and use the result of the synthesis. Then you have gate-level synthesis. (The use of 'and' etc. primitives in Verilog is open for discussion if is is behavioral or not . I would claim it still is)

Comment: Yes, for that you have to start a new subject.

Comment: 'new subject'? not getting. Can you help me to start with this? testbench?

Comment: No, you have to do that yourself. New subject: start a new thread on the forum, but it is normal that you will need to show some effort first.